# what is the Facebook Events app id?

Tags: events, widget, feed, facebook-social-plugins, app-id

I have embeded the Activity feed widget on my website, but I only want to show FB events from my FB business page - i think the script generator will do it but I don't know the Facebook Events App id?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the Activity feed works - it pulls actions taken on objects on your domain or in your app (e.g. likes of articles, posts of open graph actions) - it doesn't pull on-facebook activity for your on-Facebook page

Answer (score 0):

The following articles help you understand the concept of app ID and its usage.

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/store/edit/social/social-06.html

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/